# Questions about bus addresses

Tags: kernel, bare-metal

I've been working on my bare metal DMA code. I've heard that you need to pass bus addresses to initialize DMA control block. I want to know why you need to put 0xC or 0x4 in front of memory address for DMA to use it, why can't DMA use normal physical addresses?

Comment: I've edited this question rather than closing it as a duplicate of your last one or as "too broad" (see ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), particularly paragraph 2 and 3).  I also recommend you take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour); this site is a tool and like any other you will get the most out of it if you read the documentation.

Comment: **Note we *are not* a discussion forum,** and people who are used to that are often confused by the Q&A format, which places more of an explicit set of responsibilities on the person asking the question.  A theme common to both those questions is making very little effort to fish for potentially large volumes of information -- that's what search engines are for, and we aren't one of those either.  To draw an analogy, don't deposit $5 in the bank expecting to come back in a few days and find $10,000.  If that's what you need to do, a casino is a more appropriate venue.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use normal addresses because the DMA hardware is directly connected to the memory bus and uses (physical) bus addresses.

```
Beware that the DMA controller is directly connected to the peripherals.
Thus the DMA controller must be set-up to use the Physical (hardware)
addresses of the peripherals.
```

Page 38 [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf)